# Can a recursive function containing a for loop that contains a call of the mentioned function be implemented using only for loops?

Tags: loops, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops, theory

Similar questions have been asked and the general consensus is that anything can be converted from recursion to for loops and vice versa. However, I can't find a way to convert a function of the following pseudocode type to a for loop:

```
def recursive(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    for i in range(some_number):
        do_sth...
        recursive(n-1)
```

In this case, there is n nested loops and n varies depending on the given argument. When using only for loops, the number of nested loops seems to be always predetermined in the code, it doesn't vary depending on "input". Is there a way to make something like this using only for loops?

Comment: Is the consensus you're referring to specific for loops with predetermined number of cycles? IMO it doesn't make sense... maybe it's just that "every algorithm where a function calls itself can be implemented without a function actually calling itself"?

Comment: @obe the consensus is that anything can that can be implemented using of those can be implemented using the other. In other words, yes, it's what you said, but it seems to me that it doesn't apply to situations in which the number of nested loops is not predetermined.

Comment: In the "worst case" you could implement a local stack data structure and an infinite loop that would mimic a recursion. This can work in all cases, and you won't have a function calling itself, but I'm not sure if it would still be considered "not using recursion", because it just moves the stack-related instructions that are generated by the compiler (and the hardware-level instructions like `CALL` and `RET`) to your "user space" code. However, it can help with stack-overflow issues when your nesting is too deep for the available "built-in" stack size).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make something like this using only for loops?

Well, if you admit a *while* loop as a case of a pseudocode *for* loop, at least your example can be made:

```
def nonrecursive(n):
  a = []
  z = 0
  while n:
    while n:
      i = z
      if i == some_number: break
      print((n, i))
      a += [[n, i]]
      n -= 1
      z = 0
    if not a: break
    n, i = a.pop()
    i += 1
    z = i
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to be careful here.

The general true statement is that loops can replace recursion and vice versa. This can be shown lots of ways; see the structured programming theorem for ideas.

Whether *for* loops can replace recursion depends upon your definitions. Can your for loops run forever, or for an indefinite amount of time not known in advance? If so, they are functionally equivalent to while loops, and they can replace recursion. If your for loops cannot be made to run forever or for an unknown (initially) number of iterations, recursion cannot always be replaced.

Really, it's while loops (plus a stack data structure) that can replace recursion without much trouble.